# How to get a table name inside a pg query with json?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, nosql

I'm trying to get a json with a table name inside with a row, I've trying:

Create a table:

```
create table if not exists customer (
    _id serial,
    first_name varchar(50),
    constraint pk_customer primary key (_id)
);
```

Insert some data:

```
insert into customer(first_name) values ('Customer1');
```

Then:

```
SELECT json_agg(customer) as customer FROM customer;
```

**Result:**

```
[{"_id":1,"first_name":"Customer1"}, 
 {"_id":2,"first_name":"Customer2"}]
```

**Expected Result:**

```
{
   "Customer":[
      {
         "_id":1,
         "first_name":"Customer1"
      },
      {
         "_id":2,
         "first_name":"Customer2"
      }
   ]
}
```

Someone knows if this is possible directly from database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a nested json you have to build it with `json_build_object`

you should also check the other json functions https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-json.html

> ```
> SELECT json_build_object('Customer',json_agg(customer)) as customer FROM customer;
> ```

> ```
> | customer                                                                                     |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | {"Customer" : [{"_id":1,"first_name":"Customer1"}, <br> {"_id":2,"first_name":"Customer2"}]} |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ef44904c3fb125b3c282926d5224f19d)*